# ADB says device unauthorized

Tags: android, adb, cyanogenmod, usb-debugging

I tried installing cyanogenmod on my samsung s2. I managed to sucessfully install **cyanogen recovery** on the device which boots up when I start the device.

After that I tried to install cyanogenmod which gets me an error:

```
adb push "cm-12.1-20160129-NIGHTLY-i9100.zip" /storage/sdcard0
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

I already tried to kill and restart `adb` server and also tried installing different `usb` drivers using Zadig`.`

I have read that **USB debugging** must be enabled on the device but the problem is that **I cannot boot android anymore** to set that option, I only get a start screen with a **yellow exclamation mark** and right after that cyanogenmod recovery menu shows up. Iam not sure if this option is the source of the problem, though.

Is the device bricked now or is there a way to either install cyanogenmod or at least restore the original android?

Comment: *I did a factory reset which could have reset the option, right?* yep

Comment: I did the "factory reset/wipe data" from within the cyanogenmod recovery. However, I can not boot android so how can I set the option now?

Comment: Why -1? Instead of just downvoting the question someone could try to help or at least explain why. I though installing cyanogenmod can't be that hard. Seems I was totally wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now simply solved the problem by copying the cyanogenmod zip on the sdcard of another phone, then put this sdcard in my phone and then simply installing from sdcard via cyanogenmod recovery menu.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the sideload function:

1. Open you CyanogenMod Recovery
2. Apply update -> Apply from ADB
3. Your terminal should now show your device as sideloaded
4. type: `adb sideload cm-12.1-20160129-NIGHTLY-i9100.zip`
   done

Comment: Thanks, the step 2 is the crucial one !

Comment: In my case this is the correct answer, at which I needed to enter the shell while  inside cynogenmod recovery mode

Answer (score -2):

The solution for me that work well is

1 - adb kill-server

2 - sudo adb usb

after this you mobile will ask for authorization and work well. so, adb needs root privilege.

Comment: The authentication is on the device side, not the host, so elevating host privileges would not do anything.